# How to show Total Amount in a Textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox for the Amount and I would like the following statement to display it.

Below are my code:

```
<!--Amount-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-lg-4">
            Amount</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBudget" runat="server" class="form-control" AutoPostBack="True" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
 void GetTotalAmount()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Materials.SellingPrice + Equipments.Price + Resource_Vehicles.Cost + Contractors.Rate) " +
    "FROM ProjectTasks INNER JOIN Resource_Contractors ON ProjectTasks.TaskID = Resource_Contractors.TaskID INNER JOIN " +
    "Resource_Equipments ON ProjectTasks.TaskID = Resource_Equipments.TaskID INNER JOIN Resource_Materials ON ProjectTasks.TaskID = Resource_Materials.TaskID INNER JOIN " +
    "Resource_Vehicles ON ProjectTasks.TaskID = Resource_Vehicles.TaskID INNER JOIN Contractors ON Resource_Contractors.ContractorID = Contractors.ContractorID INNER JOIN " +
    "Materials ON Resource_Materials.MaterialID = Materials.MaterialID INNER JOIN Equipments ON Resource_Equipments.EquipmentID = Equipments.EquipmentID INNER JOIN " +
    "Vehicles ON Resource_Vehicles.VehicleID = Vehicles.VehicleID WHERE ProjectTasks.TaskID=@TaskID";
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can add-  txtBudget.Text = Convert.ToString(dr);
line after  SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: I deleted my answer in favour of the two below but worth adding that you are not assigning a parameter value.   Before you execute the command you need something like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskID", taskid);` Where `tasked` = the `id` you want.  Some would argue that you shouldn't use `AddWithValue` but with some datatypes it really isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3):

If your query is okey, just use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get this value and assign your textbox's `Text` property. You don't need to use `ExecuteReader` for that.

```
var sum = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
txtBudget.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command like;

```
void GetTotalAmount()
{
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
       cmd.CommandText = "...";
       con.Open();
       var sum = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
       txtBudget.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: use `var sum=cmd.ExecuteScalar();` coz it might have double or decimal

Comment: @Satindersingh Yeah, that can be. Changed that part.

Comment: txtBudget.Text = i.ToString();

What does the i stands for?

Comment: @JelloDeMatta Ups, it should be `sum`. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use [`SqlDataReader.GetDouble`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdouble(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) // use using for everything implementing IDisposable, also connection
{
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        dr.Read(); // advances reader to first record
        txtBudget.Text = dr.GetDouble(0).ToString();
    }
}
```

another approach is using `ExecuteScalar` if you just select a single value(as shown by Soner).